# Google Maps / SQL - add links to field in info panel

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

I have just about got the Google Maps API all connected to a mySQL database, but just have one thing I haven't been able to figure out as my background isn't really in javascript.

I have a working search page here:

http://www.quakerquest.org/meeting_place_search_map/

So if you search for London, it should find quite a few.

All I would like to add to finish to off is make the venue name in the info panel a clickable link to its details page on the site,

e.g. http://www.quakerquest.org/meeting_place_details/index.php?VenueID=190

The API code on the page looks like:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow;
var locationSelect;

function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3836, -1.4665),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none"){
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };
   }

   function searchLocations() {
 var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
}

function clearLocations() {
 infoWindow.close();
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);
 }
 markers.length = 0;

 locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
 var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.value = "none";
 option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
 locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
 clearLocations();

 var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
 var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' +     center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
     var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Venue");
     var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
     var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     createOption(name, distance, i);
     createMarker(latlng, name, address);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
   locationSelect.onchange = function() {
     var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
   };
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

function createOption(name, distance, num) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
```

Where

```
var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Venue");
```

Venue is the string I would like to be the clickable link.

If anyone could help out with this I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You want a [sidebar like this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html)?

Comment: No - just want some of the text in the info panel itself to act as a link to another page on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address, venueId, nameId) {

  // this is what you change to update the infowindow
  var html = "<a href='http://www.quakerquest.org/meeting_place_details/index.php?VenueID="+venueId+"&nameID="+nameId+"'>" + name + "</a>"

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

Now I'm assuming you want the link to be dynamic and come from the xml data, so you would have to add that parameter to createMarker() and then dynamically change the href attribute.

Comment: Thanks - from that I am nearly there. I added another variable to store the VenueID from the XML, and that is displaying correctly as, for example, 190 Finchley Quaker Meeting. So the only thing I'm not sure of is the syntax to use that nameID in the URL. So presume its something like  <a href="http://www.quakerquest.org/meeting_place_details/index.php?VenueID="'nameID>'">

Comment: Thanks Bryant - that's not quite right though. I have these vars from the XML - var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("Venue"); var nameID = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("VenueID"); I've played around with it a bit, but haven't got it. Must be close though.

Comment: It might be something to do with single or double quotes. From your first reply, it didn't like var html = "<a href= but was OK with var html = '<a href=

Comment: Oops, I missed a double quote at the end.

Comment: Thank you - that's all working now with a slight tweak: var html = "<a href='http://www.quakerquest.org/meeting_place_details/index.php?VenueID="+nameID+"'>" + name + "</a> <br/>" + address; Really appreciate you helping out with that.

Comment: Done - thanks again. Although I just noticed the zoom bar isn't displaying properly. Not sure if you'd have any idea what might be causing that, but I have asked a separate question about it.